# Which statistical test to use? I am really confused.

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a research paper; I used two scales to measure marital adjustment and social roles.

I applied them to 150 people.

I would like say something about how males who got high scores on the social roles scale compare to women who also got high scores on marital adjustment scores, or vise versa.

The scores are both interval measures.

I'm confused what tests to use.

I want to test a hypothesis that if men get higher social role scores and women get higher on social role scores, then marital adjustment scores are also higher.

Comment: Are the men and women *couples*? That is, are you asking whether marital adjustment for both the man and woman in a heterosexual marriage depends on the social role of each spouse?

Comment: What have you tried or considered so far?  For you to be confused, you must be conflicted as to whether certain procedures are going to be right for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a general linear model: the response is marital adjustement, the independent variables are gender and social role. You could also include an interaction term with gender and social role -- maybe social role improves marital adjustment for both men and women, but has a bigger impact on men. The interaction effect would allow you to test that possibility.

If the men and women are couples, then it's a whole other ball game. You would want a multivariate model of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Placidia.

response variable - marital adjustment score (continuous)

predictors - social role score and gender

Multivariate regression or MANCOVA can be used.